# How do I create a dropdown list in a word doc that is using a template?

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I am trying to create a dropdown in a word doc that is generated using a template (this is all done through a button click in access). When the code is run, it stops at the line for creating the dropdown and gives the following error:

> Run-time error '445':
>   Object doesn't support this action

I've narrowed down the problem to this line:

> Set doc = oWord.Documents.Add(strWordTemplate)

The dropdown appears no problem when 'strWordTemplate' is removed from 'Add()'. That only gives me a blank document with the dropdown though. How can I place a dropdown in the document generated via the template?

strWordTemplate is a file location for a calendar template for word. TemplatePath is a global string constant to where the word templates are held. Ideally, I would be placing the same dropdown list (same values) in each cell of the calendar, but I want to figure out how to get both the template and the dropdown to show up in the same document first

```vb
Public Sub MakeCalendar()
Dim strWordTemplate As String
Dim oWord As Object
Dim doc As Word.Document

    'Open a Word Doc With the Template
    Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.application")
    oWord.Visible = False
    oWord.DisplayAlerts = False

    strWordTemplate = TemplatePath & "Calendar.dot"
    Set doc = oWord.Documents.Add(strWordTemplate) 'template is added here

    doc.ContentControls.Add wdContentControlDropdownList 'having the template added causes this line to fail

    'Show the Word Doc
    oWord.DisplayAlerts = True
    oWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The command you show will replace all the content in the document with the content control. Try declarting and instantiating a `Word.Range` object and assign the target position for the control to it. And I see nothing in the code shown that has anything to do with tables - exactly what needs to happen is unclear.

Comment: I edited the post to fix my miswording. Also, would I just Dim temp As Word.Range and then: doc.temp.contentcontrols... or is there another step?

Comment: If you're answering someone, remember to "ping" them using @, for example @BoatHouse otherwise the person won't be notified. And, yes, content controls were new in 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried your (modified) code from excel as I am consider myself Zero in Access (more Accurately i used to run from Access). it works and hope will address your issue as below
[image]

and the Code is self explantory

```
Public Sub MakeCalendar()
Dim strWordTemplate As String
Dim oWord As Object
Dim doc As Word.Document

Dim TemplatePath As String
Dim Tbl As Table, cl As Cell, Rw As Row
'Modify/Delete to your requirement, but take care that last slash ("\") is in place in the path
'it is the most probable cause of error in your code
'It in first place it failed to open the template, but does not give alerts
'as DisplayAlerts set to false and then gives eroor 424 on next line
TemplatePath = "C:\users\user\desktop\"

    'Open a Word Doc With the Template
    Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.application")
    oWord.Visible = True                     ' modify to your choice
    oWord.DisplayAlerts = True               ' modify to your choice

    strWordTemplate = TemplatePath & "Calendar.dotx"
    Set doc = oWord.Documents.Add(strWordTemplate) 'template is added here
    Set Tbl = doc.Tables(1)                      ' Modify to your requirement

    For Each Rw In doc.Tables(1).Rows
    For Each cl In Rw.Cells
    cl.Range.ContentControls.Add wdContentControlDropdownList
    Next cl
    Next Rw
     ' Or use your original code
    'doc.ContentControls.Add wdContentControlDropdownList 'having the template added causes this line to fail

    'Show the Word Doc
    oWord.DisplayAlerts = True
    oWord.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Just now seeing this. I gave your code a shot, but I still got the same error. I even moved the template from its original location to the desktop and hard coded strWordTemplate to that location. still got the same issue. If it helps any, setting the display alerts and visible to True gave me 2 seperate word docs. one with the table, and one blank one. Could the ".dot" instead of ".dotx" be the issue?

Comment: I actually tried changing the ".dot" file to a ".dotx" and it fixed the issue. I guess the dropdown was new to word 2007 so 2003 templates wouldn't accept the command